# Why can't i push to git origin master?

Tags: git, github

I tried pushing to the origin master some code and got a weird problem, can anybody help please?

Here is the git bash:
[image: Here is the git bash]

The code can be found in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y8ulwvdfw6exbc4/AABIliu4PSm7cRi_KP96BXdfa?dl=0).

Comment: "Permission denied (publickey)" means you've either misconfigured the public key in your GitHub account, or are mistakenly using an unintended key.

Comment: Please copy and paste the Bash text into your question instead of making screenshots of it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try testing your SSH connection as outlined in [GitHub's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)?  It appears your public key is not being accepted, which means you forgot to add your SSH key to the account, or you're attempting to use a different SSH key than the one you added.

Comment: Tank you, i have tested it before but maybe it has changed somehow

Answer (score 0):

A "Permission denied" error means that the server rejected your connection. There could be several reasons why, and the most common examples are explained in [this post](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/).

Comment: Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer